# Defined dict entries Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Any ideas how to make something like the following?

Let there be:

```
a = {'p': 1, 'r': 2}
b = {'p': 1, 'r': 3}
```

This is a simplified entry, however imagine that there are more common key-value pairs, so the goal is to make the definition smaller and more readable. Is there any way to alias it such that I can write e.g.:

```
m = ('p': 1)  # note this does not work
a = {m, 'r': 2}
b = {m, 'r': 3}
```

Here's an obfuscated version of my issue:

```
what = {
        sr: [{'los_angels': mg, 'sg': sg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'sg': sg, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'}],
        as: [{'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle}, {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle},
                {'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'},
                {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'}],
        dd: [{'los_angels': 'orange', 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': 'orange', 'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston},
                    {'los_angels': 'orange', 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'},
                    {'los_angels': 'orange', 'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston, 'apple': 'IS'}],
        a: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        b: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        c: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        d: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        e: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        f: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        g: [{}],
        h: [{}],
        i: [{}, {'los_angels': mg}],
    }
```

So I'm looking for some way to make the 'los_angels': 'orange' part,  'ua':boston smaller :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a predefined key-value pair like that, no, but there are other options:

- You could define a base dictionary, then update `a` and `b` with it:

  ```
  m = {'p': 1}
  a = {'r': 2}
  a.update(m)
  b = {'r': 3}
  a.update(m)
  ```
- You could use the `dict()` function to combine two dictionaries into one new one, or to add additional keys as keyword arguments:

  ```
  m = {'p': 1}
  a = dict(m, r=2)
  b = dict(m, r=3)
  ```

  This requires the other keys (like `r`) to be [valid Python identifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). You could use the `**` syntax to work around that limitation:

  ```
  m = {'p': 1}
  a = dict(m, **{'r': 2})
  b = dict(m, **{'r': 3})
  ```

  Now `r` can be any string again.
- You could define the key and value as separate variables, and use those:

  ```
  m_key, m_value = 'p', 1
  a = {m_key: m_value, 'r': 2}
  b = {m_key: m_value, 'r': 3}
  ```

Applying the second option to your obfuscated sample:

```
la_orange = {'los_angels': 'orange'}

what = {
        sr: [{'los_angels': mg, 'sg': sg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'sg': sg, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'},
                    {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'}],
        as: [{'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle}, {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle},
                {'los_angels': mg, 'ua': boston, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'},
                {'los_angels': mg, 'new_york': seattle, 'apple': 'IS'}],
        dd: [dict(la_orange, new_york=seattle),
                    dict(la_orange, new_york=seattle, ua=boston),
                    dict(la_orange, new_york=seattle, apple='IS'),
                    dict(la_orange, new_york=seattle, ua=boston, apple='IS')],
        a: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        b: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        c: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        d: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        e: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        f: [{}, {'ua': boston}, {'new_york': seattle}, {'new_york': seattle, 'ua': boston}],
        g: [{}],
        h: [{}],
        i: [{}, {'los_angels': mg}],
    }
```

If you need to combine multiple such pre-defined dictionaries, you can create a helper function:

```
def combine_dicts(*d, **kw):
    """Combine dictionaries into one.

    Keys in later dictionaries override those in earlier dictionaries, with
    keyword arguments being applied last.

    """
    return reduce(lambda d1, d2: dict(d1, **d2), d + (kw,))
```

then use this with:

```
a = combine_dicts(base1, base2, {'some non-identifier key': 42}, r=3)
```

Comment: Ok, so let's make things more general, asssume I have n such common entries in a few dicts :) and I have a few custom ones :)

Comment: @Yeti: The first two approaches can handle any size of base-dictionary to expand on.

Comment: Not quite what I need, so I've added an obsufcated version of my issue :) this is basically a config object defintion :)

Comment: @Yeti: each one of those dictionaries with `{'los_angels': 'orange'}` in it can be handled with the second option.

Comment: Yeah but if I have more elements they are not easily used together: a={'los_angels': 'orange'}, b={'ua':boston} cannot be written then as dict(a, b, s=2) composibilaty it's not straight forward :)

Comment: @Yeti: you can nest `dict()` calls, or use a helper function. I'll add one.

Answer (score 0):

You only need a minimal change to your code:

```
m=(('p',1),)
a=dict(m, r=2)
b=dict(m, r=3)
```